# Unable to get params Node and Angular

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

I have a list of todos that are fetched from MongoDB and they are displayed on one page and when I click on one it opens on another page with URL that equals clicked todo. Now I am trying to get the id from URL and send it to node server but I can't get it.

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params
   .subscribe(
    (params: Params) => {
      let todoId = params['userId'];
      console.log(todoId);
    }
  );
}
```

console returns undefined.
I found one solution where id is fetched by this line of code, but it only gets id once and when I click on another todo it doesn't log anything.

```
 let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
 console.log(id)
```

And when I want to send request to server with this:

```
let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
   this.todoService.getSingleTodo(id)
    .subscribe(
      (todo: Todo) => {
        this.todo = todo;
        console.log(todo);
      }
    );
```

I got this error in console "message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \":id\" at path \"_id\"

Service looks like this:

```
    getSingleTodo(id) {
     return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/todos/:id')
        .map( response => response.json().obj)
        .map( todo => todo.map(todo => new Todo(todo.todoHeadline, 
     todo.todoDescription, todo._id)));
}
```

And node file:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.params.id);
Todo.findById(req.params.id, (err, singleTodo) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            title: 'An error occured',
            error:err
        });
    }
     res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Success',
        obj: singleTodo
        });
    });
});
```

Also this console prints :id.

Main routing file

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/auth', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'todos', component: TodoComponent, children: TODO_ROUTES},
{ path: 'auth', component: AuthenticationComponent, children: AUTH_ROUTES }
];
```

And children routes for todos

```
export const TODO_ROUTES: Routes = [
{path: 'todo/add', component: TodoAddComponent},
{path: ':id', component: TodoListComponent},
{path: 'edit', component: TodoEditComponent}
];
```

HTML where all todos are displayed lools like this

```
<ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item"
      *ngFor="let todo of todos;"
      [routerLink]="['/todos', todo.todoId]">{{todo.todoHeadline}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this line right here that's wrong:

```
let todoId = params['userId'];
```

In your Routing, you defined that the path variable would be named "id":

```
{path: ':id', component: TodoListComponent},
```

So when you try to access a path variable userId, it obviously returns undefined.

Comment: Omg, what a stupid mistake I made. Thank you. I've been busting my head for past 2  hours trying to find the mistake.